# PDF file checkbox validation for printing?

Tags: javascript, pdf, scripting, acrobat

I have a PDF document which has 2 checkboxes. I have validated them in Acrobat pro X.

My question is how do I prevent the document from being printed without checking either one of the checkboxes ? User has to check least 1 checkbox before the document can be printed.

I got checkbox1 and checkbox2

How do I do this via Javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this an [tag:acrobat] question or a [tag:javascript] question?

Comment: Hi I'm trying to validate the checkbox fields in acrobat reader X. This is done via Javascript. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look; http://www.pdfscripting.com/